# Generate User reports in Access database automatically

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good Afternoon All,

About twice a year at my company I have to generate user reports for certain managers. I have no problem generating these reports and sending them to the proper user but this always requires operator action on my teams end. I wanted to see if there was an easier way to do this. My idea was to generate and email these mass reports using a single button. Could I do this through VBA or Macros? Or should I not have to go that route because there is a simpler way?

Thanks guys for any help.

Comment: You could use VBA, or likely any one of a number of available reporting tools. Which is "best" for you will depend on what your existing skill level is. Question is too broad and not really on-topic for this site though.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I did VBA ages ago, so I wasnt sure if that was appropriate for this task. I would be considered a beginner.

Comment: I really just needed to know if this type of task was possible.

Comment: Yes - definitely possible in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can. Since you are asking only for direction, and this is not a freelancer group so that you can expect people write the whole code for you, I only give you a part that I already had on one of my files and explain how you should do the rest.

I am not sure the report you have will be presented in Excel, word or any other file, but the main idea would be to write a vba code that runs your queries and collects data and formats it in a way you want. That would be your challenge to figure out the details and you will not get the answer to all of your questions in one single posting.

For the part that you want to email, here is the code that I can help you with:

```
Sub Email_Recepients(sEMailSubj As String, sPath As String, sBody As String)
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object

    If bolHandleErrors Then On Error GoTo Handler

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'    olApp.Visible=True
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    With olMail
        .To = Mat_EmailAddress
        .Subject = sEMailSubj
'        .Attachments.Add sPath
'        .DeleteAfterSubmit = True
'        .HTMLBody = sBody
'        .Send
    End With
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
    Exit Sub

Handler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Oops! Something went worng. I could not get Outlook to send your                  message. Please try again later.",vbInformation, "Email HHI Governance Function"

  End Sub
```

some of the lines have been commented out, but you can uncomment them and use them if you wanted to. Make sure you define variables that they use at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful!

Comment: if you hit the check mark as an answer for your question, it would help me too, thanks! BTW, if you ask more specific and granular questions, you will be able to eventually build up your code. People are awesome!

Comment: Got it! People have been very helpful here